# Funcionamento das funções para manipulação de arquivos

Tags: php

Eu sei qual a sintaxe, a lógica da função. Eu gostaria de saber como isso funciona no fundo. Exemplo, eu dei a função `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `fwrite()`, o que na verdade eu estou fazendo? Seria possível escrever essas funções na mão? Como? 
Se não for possível, o que ocorre então para eu conseguir abrir arquivos, fechar, etc.. ?

Obrigado!

Comment: Essas funções são basicamente wrappers para as equivalentes em C.

Comment: Ta ai uma pergunta bacana, já tenho alguma experiência em PHP, mas realmente não sei dizer se é possível. Mas creio que não seja possível. Acho que isso é uma tarefa para o interpretador do PHP, onde deva ter alguma biblioteca em C ou algo parecido. Aguardando respostas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP é escrito em cima de C, portanto o que essas funções fazem é [*simplesmente*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L861)  chamar `fopen()`, `fclose()`, e outras funções da [`stdio.h`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdio_h.htm) de C.

Portanto você não pode acessar diretamente um arquivo no sistema de arquivos sem usar essas funções que o PHP disponibiliza.

Se você quiser saber mais como C faz a leitura de um arquivo leia [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5130577/1042324) no SO.